# How to stop printing dump.txt while using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I'm using Android studio to generate apk file,but my project is too big and it costs a lot of time.Besides,it costs about 30 seconds print dump.txt and its size is 450MB.So I want to stop printing this file ,do you have ideas?Thank you.